# uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies, sprockets

In updating dependencies, I have come across updating `sprockets`. However there doe not appear to be a proper dependency for my set of gems. After returning to: 2.11.3, the erorr apepars:

```
/Users/..../rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)
```

*Gemfile:*

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'  # '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
#gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'mysql2', '0.4.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'geocoder', '1.3.7'
gem 'nested_form', '0.3.2'
gem 'utf8-cleaner', '0.2.4'
gem 'sprockets', '3.6.0' #2.11.3
gem 'json', '1.8.3'
gem 'ffi'
gem 'iconv', '1.0.4'

gem 'chosen-rails', '1.5.2'
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'

# For image uploads
gem 'carrierwave', '0.11.2'

# For uploading CSV
gem 'roo', '2.4.0'

# DataTables
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '3.4.0' #  git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'

# Editing in line:
gem 'best_in_place', '3.1.0'

# Passing data from controller to coffeescript
gem 'gon', '6.0.1'
#gem 'jquery-turbolinks' '2.1.0'

# For searching and webservice queries-NO LONGER USED
#gem 'sunspot_rails', '2.1.0'
#gem 'sunspot_solr', '2.1.0'
gem 'progress_bar', '1.0.5'

gem 'responders', '2.2.0'

# Calendar Date and Validation
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

# For Google Maps overlays
gem 'gmaps4rails', '~> 2.1.2'
gem 'underscore-rails', '~> 1.8.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.4.2'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '4.7.2'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.5.9'
  gem 'guard-spork', '2.1.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.3'
  gem 'capybara', '2.7.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.7.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.5.3'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.5.0'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.1', require: false
end

gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.3'
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem following steps:

**First**, you run `gem update` to update your `gems`.

And `sprockets-rails` should be at `version 3.0.4`

**Second**, open your `Gemfile.lock` in your rails project, modify the following line to update `sprocket` version

`sprockets-rails (3.0.4)`

**Finally**, you run `bundle install`

Comment: I think you meant `bundle update`. But that won't work either because all of the gem versions are locked to specific versions in their Gemfile. This is not the correct way to use the Gemfile, there's no way to upgrade any gems in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Above one is the answer, 
You can fix this problem following steps:

First, you run gem update to update your gems.

And sprockets-rails should be at version 3.0.4

Second, open your Gemfile.lock in your rails project, modify the following line to update sprocket version

sprockets-rails (3.0.4)

Finally, you run bundle install